# How do you in SAS return the list of all columns in all tables in a library that contain a target value?

Tags: search, sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to map out fields I see in an application to columns in the source database using SAS EG.

If I search for 'SomeString' or someNumericValue in Library = SomeLibrary 
I want the code to output a table that lists the tableName ColumnName that contains the value searched.

Proc SQL:
Select * columns C from all tables in Library L that contain the value or string = 'SomeValue'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Proc contents` can create a table of data set names to scan.  A scanning macro, say `%scanner`, can be written and invoked for each data set via `call execute`.  The results of the scan, the data set name and column containing the target, can be appended to an 'all results' table.

Example:

For simplicity it is presumed no data set has more than 10K variables of the target value type -- the code issues a warning if the scanning will be clipped.

Note: Example of string target would be `..., target="Jane", ...`

```
%macro scanner (libname=, memname=, target=20500, flagMax = 10000);
  %local type;

  %if %qsysfunc(dequote(&target)) = %superq(target) %then 
    %let type = _numeric_;
  %else 
    %let type = _character_;

  data hits(keep=__libname __memname __varname);
    array __flag (&flagMax) _temporary_;

    set &libname..&memname;

    array __candidates &type;

    if dim(__candidates) = 0 then stop;

    do __index = 1 to min (dim(__candidates), &flagMax);
      if not __flag(__index) then 
        if __candidates(__index) = &target then do;
          length __libname $8;
          length __memname __varname $32;
          __libname = "&libname";
          __memname = "&memname";
          __varname = vname(__candidates(__index));
          __flag(__index) = 1;

          OUTPUT;
        end;          
    end;

    if _n_ = 1 then
      if dim(__candidates) > &flagMax then put "WARNING: &memname has more than &flagMax variables - scanning will be clipped. Increase flagMax=.";
  run;

  proc append base=hasTarget data=hits(rename=(__libname=libname __memname=memname __varname=varname));
  run;
%mend;

proc sql;
  create table hasTarget (libname char(8), memname char(32), varname char(32));
quit;

%let libname = SASHELP;

ods noresults;
ods output members=datasets;
proc datasets library=&libname memtype=data;
run;
quit;
ods results;

data _null_;
  set datasets(keep=name memtype);
  where memtype = 'DATA';

  call execute (cats('%nrstr(%scanner(libname=' || "&LIBNAME., " || "memname=", name, '))'));
run;
```

Comment: Also, how would one skip specific tables in the searched library? for instance in <library> has tables A,B,C,D and I know Table C is large and irrelevant, then can I tell the macro to skip Table C in the automation?

Comment: Add a `where` or `if` to the final `data _null_` before the `execute` that launches the scans. For example: `if NOT (libname="BIGGY" and memname="C");`

Comment: Amazing solution!

Comment: Where do I specify the lib to search: in `%let libname = SASHELP;` change `SASHELP` to my lib? Then confirming the string portion, change the string value in `target=20500` to something like `target="Jane"`?

Comment: You can specify those directly in the `call execute`.    `call execute (cats('%nrstr(%scanner(target="Jane", libname=MyLib, memname=', name, '))'));`

Answer (score 0):

Great challenge!  I can get you some of the way there - the `mp_searchdata` macro of the SASjs [macro core library](https://github.com/sasjs/core) will query all tables in a library (source database) for a string or numeric value.  It returns all columns, but will filter for only matching records.

To execute:

```
/* import library */
filename mc url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasjs/core/main/all.sas";
%inc mc;

/* run macro */
%mp_searchdata(lib=yourlib, string=SomeString)
```

Comment: I get the following Errors when trying to execute this: 

ERROR: The connection was reset by a peer..
ERROR: Cannot open %INCLUDE file MC.

Even when I copy the code in, I get an error when trying to execute the macro: 

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

Comment: you may not have access from your web server.  Just download and compile the macros separately:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sasjs/core/main/all.sas

Answer (score 0):

It is a nice question, i myself wanted to develop the code for me .. you can try following code to find the table names from a library, exact variable names which has the required value

## Modified Code

```
libname temp "Y:\temp\t";
data temp.aa;
a=0;
b=0;
test="String";
run;

data temp.bb;
a=1;
c=0;
d=1;
run;

data temp.cc;
a=0;
b=1;
e=1;
run;

proc sql;
create table info
as
select memname as table, name as column from dictionary.columns
where upcase(type)="NUM" /*upcase(type)="CHAR"*/
and libname='TEMP'
order by memname;
quit;

options merror mprint nosymbolgen nomlogic;
data info1;
length coltab $1000.;
 set info;
 newtab=catx("_","TEMPT",_n_);
 condition=column||"=1"; /*Set Desired value here*/
 tab=("'"||table||"' as tab_name");
 var=("'"||column||"' as var_name");
 coltab="create table "||newtab||" as Select "||column||","||tab||","||var||" from temp."||table|| "where "||condition||";";
run;

proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into: nobs from info1;
quit;

%macro process;
%do i=1 %to &nobs;
    Data _null_;
        Set info1(firstobs=&i obs=&i);
        call symput('query',coltab);
    run;
    proc sql noprint;
        &Query;
    quit;
%end;
%mend;

%process;

proc sql noprint;
select distinct memname into :gt separated by " " from dictionary.columns where memname like '%TEMPT%';
quit;

%macro split(var);
%let var_c=%sysfunc(countw(&var));
%do i=1 %to &var_c;
    %let var_t=%sysfunc(scan(&var,&i));

    proc sql noprint;
    select count(*) into :cnt from &var_t;
    quit;

    %if &cnt=0 %then
    %do;
        proc datasets lib=work nolist;   
        delete &var_t; 
        quit;
        run;
    %end;
%end;
%mend split;

%split(&gt);

proc sql noprint;
select distinct memname into :gt0 separated by " " from dictionary.columns where memname like '%TEMPT%';
quit;

data all;
 set &gt0;
 keep tab_name var_name;
run;

proc sort data=all; by tab_name; run;

data final;
length vars $100.;
 set all;
  by tab_name;
  retain vars '';
  if first.tab_name then vars=var_name;
  else vars=catx(",",vars,var_name);
  if last.tab_name;
  drop var_name;
run;

proc print data=final; run;
```

Comment: I get the following error after switching my search string and Variable. My string is only 10 characters long... 

ERROR: The length of the value of the macro variable COLTAB (65540) exceeds the maximum length (65534). The value has been 
       truncated to 65534 characters.

Comment: Not too sure if this code handles tables/datasets that have a mix of character and numeric variables. Is there a way for it to ignore numeric columns when iterating?

Comment: I have modified the code for your first error, it should be fine now. Because now it will loop through each observation and execute the query separately, instead of creating a big string.

Comment: Also, to answer your second concern - yes you can control the types char/num based on the logic - upcase(type)="CHAR" .. or "NUM" while extracting data from dictionary.columns. So I have tweaked the sample dataset a bit and included a character variablefor your reference. I am using only Numbers and ignoring characters, you can do vice-versa.. so if you would want to search a string then change this line : condition=column||"='String'"; /*Set Desired value here*/ and use upcase(type)="CHAR"